# reduce moviepy processing time

Tags: python, ffmpeg, moviepy

I'm adding image & text to a video at a particular time only, this is the only change I'm doing to the video. But in the moviepy progress bar I can see that it goes over the rest of the frames in video even after the specified timeline. Probably this extra processing is causing it to take much more time than just the code specified changes.

Is there a way I can tell moveipy to ignore rest of the video & close the video file and exit ? this way probably it'll perform faster.

Please also indicate if there is any other ways to speed up the performance of moviepy ?

Comment: Did you forget to post your code?

Comment: its a very standard operation thats why did not post any code